# WSO2 IS 5.9 fails to start

Tags: wso2-identity-server

after updating the OS linux where I have installed IS 5.9, wso2 is failed to start and shows this error:

```
Failed to activate Registry Core bundle java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.SymLinkHandler.setTargetPoint(SymLinkHandler.java:481)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.registerHandlerForSymbolicLinks(RegistryUtils.java:1578)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.registerMountPoints(RegistryUtils.java:1105)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:222)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.<init>(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:598)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:520)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:123)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:73)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue and I cannot find a solution anywhere. Did you solved your issue? can you share what was it?

Comment: Hi, the registry file seems to be corrupted (an internal file). I copied the main file system files from a backup and it started